# Custom cell width for one collectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have 3 collectionViews in one view controller. One has all cells of the same width and does not change. The other I would like to set the cell width in code using a constant. The last will calculate its cell's width based on the previous constant and other factors in a custom flow layout.

I tried

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
             if collectionView == neededCollectionView {
             return CGSize(width: constantWidth, height: constHeight)
             } else {
                // here ignore all the others and tell them to get this size as usual
             }
        }

    }
```

but this seems to modify the width for all the collection views .. How do I get this two ignore the 2 collection views that have their size calculated somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

in this function you can't ignore, 
you need to return

> CGSize

always.

try a break point and check if it gets into the else closure if so 
you could try to add this line,

```
 return CGSize(width: yourDefualtWidthConst, height:yourDefualtHeightconst)
```

or this

```
 return collectionView.itemSize
```

Comment: but the width is not a constant.. it needs to be calculated based on the item in the cell in one of the collection view 3 .. I suppose I coulf calculate it here instead on the layout subclass...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617711-itemsize

Comment: @user426132 check the updated answer  please and note me if it works  good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have Two options

> FIRST OPTION : Return the estimatedItemSize of each CollectionViewCell

**1.**  Get an IBOutlet Reference from each CollectionViewFlowLayout
[image: UICollectionViewFlowLayoutIBOutlet]

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
```

**2.** Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate  in your viewController

**3.**  Implement the delegate method

```
func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView,layoutcollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

         if collectionView.tag == 1 {
         return CGSize(width: constantWidth, height: constHeight)
         } elseIf collectionView.tag == 2 {
         return firstFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize
         }
}
```

> SECOND OPTION : Adepter Design pattern

You can also use adapter class for each collectionview and each adapter has a different implementation to resolve this like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50920915/5233180

**NOT** : This implementation for TableView you can make it for collectionview